# How to add Imageview on WebView in Final Android App

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-webview, android-imageview

As i am going to make Alerting App, I am using my website instead of XML code. But for going to my alert activity for web Activity, I made an intent which works onclick on my small image view.

It's my XML code Below:

**activity_web.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true">


    </WebView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="81dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/bell_icon" />





</RelativeLayout>
```

But the main Problem is that imageview is not visible when I install's the app in my mobile.

> It is also visible in my android Studio Layout.

[You Check My Android Studio Layout here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPhad.png)

**Now tell me what should do for making visible it in final build apk which will work in my mobile.**

Comment: Your WebView `android:height` parameter is `match_parent` and thus it is taking up the entire parent height and your image is invisible

Comment: @gtxtreme parent is `RelativeLayout`, `WebView` won't push anything outside screen

Comment: Nope I'm not saying anything about pushing the layout outside, I'm saying it's kind of overshadowing the `ImageView` @snachmsm

Answer (score 1):

you can set it properly by using constraint layout, here is a code maybe it's work!

In this i set an ImageView at the top and webview is set at bottom of ImageView.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: image stucked at top

Comment: @YourEnglishLibrary Try setting `android:scaleType` to "center", "centerCrop" or "centerInside".

Answer (score 1):

you are using wrong attribute namespace, I'm supprised that AS preview tool is showing this image, it shouldn't. but your `ImageView` is there on device, it is clickable (wehn you set so), it just have transparent content (wrongly resolved `srcCompat` attr, as below). as a test you may add `android:background="#789810"` tag, `ImageView` will show up with visible background (still without image)

in your code you have

```
tools:srcCompat="@drawable/bell_icon"
```

`tools` namespace points on ["some tools"](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes), like used `tools:context=".WebActivity"`. for setting custom attribute of particular `View` you have to use (custom) resources namespace, these are declared in your XML with `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` line, thus you should use below line

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/bell_icon"
```

btw. if you are using `srcCompat` the you should also use `AppCompatImageView`. it works with usual `ImageView` only because AS project by default is exchanging all `ImageView`s to `AppCompatImageView`s during building project to APK/bundle. this behavior may be changed or disabled, then your `ImageView` will stay without any image set. fully proper line for setting image is default `src` attribute of `ImageView`, so:

```
android:src="@drawable/bell_icon"
```

`android` namespace in here as this attribute belong to framework ("built-in"), not some additional library and `View` (`AppCompatImageView` comes from AppCompat or AndroidX library)

Comment: Can you give me full code means give me my above whole code by clearing all errors. i am not able to solve it

Comment: I don't understand you... I've just suggested (with rich explanation) replacing `tools:srcCompat` with `app:srcCompat` or `android:src`, have you tried that? your image should be visible without any other change, with code posted in question

Comment: If i not written webview function in java file then it run's well but I am not able to show My web page

Comment: sadly I don't understand you again... You've got problem with image visibility, I've provided you explanation and solution, `WebView` itself isn't involved in this topic...

Comment: yess you gave me solution but it's not working

Comment: can you provide me your mail that I personally ask you

Comment: I'm affraid no, I'm helping only on this site. besides that I don't have any other clues, sorry...

Comment: ok no problem. My problem is that i am unable to show my image because my webview taking entire screen. If I set specific height to webview its not working any it is taking entire screen